How to create multiple instance of ViewModel using the old Dagger 2 approach?
Using the old ways with Dagger 2 for injecting ViewModel, how to create multiple instance of the same ViewModel for ViewPager?
@Singleton
class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel $modelClass. You probably forgot to include your ViewModel module to ViewModelFactory module or map it with the ViewModelKey annotation?")
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return creator.get() as T
    }
}

@Module(
    includes = [
        SampleViewModelModule::class,
        SampleCopyViewModelModule::class,
    ]
)
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

}
Modules
@Module
object SampleViewModelModule {

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SampleViewModel::class)
    fun provideSampleViewModel(
        useCase: GetSampleUseCase
    ): ViewModel = MessariPriceViewModel(useCase)

    @Provides
    @Named("FragmentOne")
    fun provideSampleViewModelProvider(
        owner: FragmentOne,
        factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    ) = ViewModelProvider(owner, factory)[SampleViewModel::class.java]

}

@Module
object SampleCopyViewModelModule {

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SampleViewModel::class)
    fun provideSampleCopyViewModel(
        useCase: GetMessariPricesUseCase
    ): ViewModel = MessariPriceViewModel(useCase)

    @Provides
    @Named("FragmentTwo")
    fun provideSampleCopyViewModelProvider(
        owner: FragmentTwo,
        factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    ) = ViewModelProvider(owner, factory)[SampleViewModel::class.java]

}

@Module
abstract class FragmentMainBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SampleModelModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeFragmentOne(): FragmentOne

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SampleCopyModelModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeFragmentTwo(): FragmentTwo

}

@Module
abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentMainBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

}

Component
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, // Default module, always on top
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class, // Injecting ViewModel happens here
        ActivityBuildersModule::class, // Injecting Activity and Fragment happens here
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    // Override the builder
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        // We can now access and inject Application class anywhere in this project
        // as long as that consumer class is also injected/registered in Dagger
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

}

Accessing it in Fragment like the below will throw build error
@Inject
@Named("FragmentOne")
override lateinit var viewModel: SampleViewModel

Error
[Dagger/MapKeys] The same map key is bound more than once

